# Hitting same API to get different number at the same time using concurrency?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, concurrency, rate-limiting

I have created a web API to generate a sequence number every time that API hits it generates a sequence number. Now, what I need is to make it concurrent for multiple users so that when multiple users at the same time hit that API then the API generates a different number every time.

Comment: how are you maintaing value of sequence number ? one ways is to use database by creating a table and generating autoincrement value so that way if ever your web server get restarted you have control of values while other way is using static but problem is it will maintain values till web server is running when its get restarted again start from begining

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on what you are trying to do and for what reason.
Generating unique sequence numbers is very difficult in an environment where you can have multiple users hitting that endpoint at the same time.

If you are trying to give them an ID to use for some sort of data insert then I suggest you don't offer integers. Instead offer GUIDs.

The issue with inserting data based on this kind of mechanism is that sometimes no data is actually inserted for various reason. users change their mind, end up requesting another id, or the subsequent call simply fails so you end up with holes in your data.

Instead offer them back GUIDs and if the call finally comes in then use it.